# Skip non-existing input paths in hadoop job

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, hadoop2

Is there an efficient way to skip non-existing input paths in hadoop job?

Iterating over the paths and checking for every file existence takes a lot of time in case of data stored in Amazon S3 and large amount of files.

Using hadoop 2.4, java